# For each value in @table variable - sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreach

Is there a way to do foreach value do something in sql server 2008.

I have a table variable that holds some IDs and i have to some more tasks based on the values.

The table vairable is as follows:

```
declare @InspectionIDTable table(InspectionID uniqueidentifier not null)
```

based on the values in this table i need to loop and run some select statements. based on the result i have to populate other table variables and do some more processing.

basically, i required foreach in sql server that can have nested foreach. Is there a clean apporach to do this.

Also, i would like to know whether it is a good approach to do this in Stored Procedure from programming point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a stored procedure and open a cursor on your "resultset"

http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/sql-server-for-each-row-next/

Anyway you should avoid to use cursors because their bad performance

There is a way to do row-by-row operations without cursors

Have a look at the below:

http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/operations-no-cursors/

Comment: will definitely take a look at them. meanwhile i got the job done via select queries using subqueries and 'IN' clauses. :)